# Can I install different packages from my own rpm-package?

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

Can I install different packages from my own rpm-package (that's my task, other variants, like shell-script is denied) on CentOS 7? I'm trying to understand spec-file format of rpmbuild, so I use some minimal configuration of this file. I'm create an rpm-package (let's call it test.rpm), launch it with "rpm -i test.rpm" and see that "yum install" from %post is launch, but stuck in "Running transaction" level of installation. SELINUX is disabled.

Here is my test.spec:

```
Name: test_script_name
Summary: It's just a test_script_summary
Version: 0.1 
Release: 1
Group: Applications/Internet
License: GPL 
BuildArch: noarch

%description
A test_script_description.

%prep 

%build

%install

%clean

%post
yum install -y lynx

%files
%defattr(-,root,root)

%changelog
* Tue Dec 08 2015 test test <test@test.com>
- test_script_changelog!
```

I'm build my test.rpm with:

```
rpmbuild --bb test.spec
```

Launch it with:

```
rpm -i test.rpm
```

And here is a part of yum output that shown during installation:

```
Total download size: 1.5 M
Installed size: 5.4 M
Downloading packages:
(1/2): centos-indexhtml-7-9.el7.centos.noarch.rpm                                               |  92 kB  00:00:00     
(2/2): lynx-2.8.8-0.3.dev15.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                      | 1.4 MB  00:00:00     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                  2.4 MB/s | 1.5 MB  00:00:00     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.
```

That's all of the output. Package didn't installed. Please, help me. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to use ```yum install test.rpm``` instead of ```rpm -i test.rpm```?Also these cases should be declared  in ```Requires``` section of spec-file.

Comment: Yes, just forgot to add it. That is the end of "yum install test.rpm" output:       Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
 Installing : test_script_name-0.1-1.noarch

Comment: lync package is not installed after this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will define this package as Requirements:

```
Requires: lynx
```

Then it will be installed as dependencies after the following command:

```
yum localinstall test.rpm
```

[look the question about autoinstallation dependencies](https://superuser.com/questions/638616/how-to-install-rpm-file-along-with-its-all-dependencies)

Comment: Really, just try to add package in "Requires" section and the package was installed! With dialog now (Is this OK [y/d/N]:), but it's ok, I'm trying to deal with it. Thank you.

Comment: `install` works just the same as `localinstall` at this point. There's no need to use `localinstall` anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Addressing OP's question: no, you cannot install one rpm from within another rpm.  To do what you want, you can list other packages as *dependencies* using the `Requires` tag.

Further reading:

- [installing an rpm from another rpm's %post script](http://lists.rpm.org/pipermail/rpm-list/2009-January/000133.html)
- [install rpm within an rpm...continued](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2006-May/msg00053.html)

RPM dependencies are discussed here:

- [Tags: Data Definitions](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-tags.html)
- [Manual Dependencies](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/s1-rpm-depend-manual-dependencies.html)

As a rule, you should use `yum` for installing (even locally built packages) to keep its database up to date.

Comment: Thank you, it's really useful for me.